# How to decode/encode a UTF-8 char in c++ without wchar_t

Tags: c++, utf-8, character-encoding

As the title states, I am attempting to decode/encode UTF-8 characters to a char, but I want to do it without using wchar_t or the like. I want to do the leg work myself. This way I know that I understand it, which I obviously don't or it would be working. I've spent about a week toying with it and am just not making progress.

I have tried several ways, yet always seem to produce incorrect results. My latest attempt:

```
ifstream ifs(FILENAME);
    if(!ifs) {
        cerr << "Open: " << FILENAME << "\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    char in;

    while (ifs >> std::noskipws >> in) {
        int sz = 1;
        if ((in & 0xc0) == 0xc0) //0xc0 = 0b11000000
        {
                sz++;
                if((in & 0xE0) == 0xE0) //0xE0 = 0b11100000
                {
                    sz++;   
                    if((in & 0xF0) == 0xF0) //0xF0 = 0b11110000
                        sz++;   
                }
        }
        cout << sz << endl;

unsigned int a = in;
    for(int i = 1; i < sz; i++) {
        ifs >> in;
        a += in;
    }
```

Why do this code not work? I simply do not understand.

EDIT: Copy+Paste spaghetti...two different var names

Comment: Uhh, `wchar_t` doesn't magically convert anything.  It's not even standard -- it's a hack.  Use properly sized character types, e.g. `char16_t` or `char32_t` if you're decoding UTF-8 into wider characters.  As for your question, you haven't said what is not working, and you don't show what datatype `c` is.  Did you mean to be testing the value of `in` (which you read in the loop) instead of `c`?  Have you tried stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: Can you be more clear about what you are encoding/decoding `UTF-8` into/from?

Comment: Also, since you are wishing to reimplement rather than use standard functions, you'd better [read the Unicode Standard](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode9.0.0/UnicodeStandard-9.0.pdf).  Version 9.0.0 is only 1036 pages.  Enjoy!

Comment: Btw, C++14 allows binary literals like `0b11000000` in the code directly. It also allows `0b1100'0000` to separate digits.

Comment: Yes, sorry c is in and length is sz

I've edited the OP to reflect.

Comment: @Galik - I am trying to translate UTF-8 bytes to a single int

Comment: @Desky So `UTF-32` in a `char32_t`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you're testing the wrong value.  Your loop is reading into the value `in`, but you are testing against some value named `c`.

When you read in additional characters, you're also going about it wrong.  You're using some value `length` instead of presumably `sz`.  And you're adding characters to an integer (which is not necessarily 32-bits by the way) instead of shifting and combining with bitwise OR.

Those are weird mistakes.  Perhaps you didn't paste your *real* code in the question, or you actually have these values lying around in scope of your function.

I would also suggest rearranging your branching, which is a bit obtuse.  The rule, according to your code is:

```
mask     |   sz
---------+-------
0xxxxxxx | 1
10xxxxxx | 1
110xxxxx | 2
1110xxxx | 3
1111xxxx | 4
```

You could define a simple table to select a size based on the upper 4 bits.

```
int sizes[16];
std::fill( sizes, sizes+16, 1 );
sizes[0xc] = 2;
sizes[0xd] = 2;
sizes[0xe] = 3;
sizes[0xf] = 4;
```

In your loop, let's fix the `c` and `length` things, use the size table to avoid silly branching, use `istream::get` instead of the stream input operator (`>>`), and combine the characters into a single value in a more normal way.

```
for( char c; ifs.get(c); )
{
    // Select correct character size (bytes)
    int sz = sizes[static_cast<unsigned char>(c) >> 4];

    // Construct character
    char32_t val = c;
    while( --sz > 0 && ifs.get(c) )
    {
        val = (val << 8) | (static_cast<char32_t>(c) & 0xff);
    }

    // Output character value in hex, unless error.
    if( ifs )
    {
        std::cout << std::hex << std::fill('0') << std::setw(8) << val << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Now, this last part concatenates the bytes in big-endian order.  I don't know if this is correct, as I haven't read the standard.  But it's much more correct than just adding values together.  It also uses a guaranteed 32-bit datatype, unlike the `unsigned int` you used.